# For apt to use local cache - apt-cacher-ng

Tags: 18.04, apt-cacher-ng

I have a host where I have installed `apt-cacher-ng` and copied over a *pre-populated cache* under `/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng`. I see that the service is running with no errors.
However, when I try to download something, `apt` still seems to try and use `archive.ubuntu.com` !
This host does not have network connectivity. How can I make sure to tell `apt` to use only the local cache ?

I have also added the following config:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99_local_proxy.conf
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://localhost:3142/";
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
Acquire::Retries "3";
```

This is the error I get:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  503  DNS error for hostname us.archive.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution. If us.archive.ubuntu.com refers to a configured cache repository, please check the corresponding configuration file. [IP: 127.0.0.1 3142]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood.

What you want is a personal repository with no traffic to the internet.
Even better, it's already been done, documented, and it's up on the Ubuntu wiki.

[Ubuntu Wiki - Personal Repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal)

Part of the directions for a personal repository is changing the sources.list to a file path.  If there are no network URLs (http/https/ftp) then apt will not go on the network.  It will only look in the locations listed in the sources.list file.

Comment: ok, so this is like PPA, but we can add any packages we want! Also, I assume that this can host more than one release - like trusty + bionic packages.

Comment: If you manually add/update packages, make sure you regenerate the meta.